# "...declared but not defined..." in header file when linking against static library

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, static-libraries, static-linking

I have a little static library "simpsonlib" which was built from one file "simpson.cpp". The library and a header file (simpson.hpp) are located in a sub-directory which is called "integrate".
Now, I'd like to link the main.cpp file with the library, so I can use the function "simpsonIntegrator()" which declared in simpson.hpp and defined in simpson.cpp (now in the library archive):

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "integrator/simpson.hpp"

int main()
{
    auto f = [](double x){
        return x*x;
    };

    std::cout << simpsonIntegrator(f,0,5,20);
    return 0;
}
```

**simpson.hpp**

```
#ifndef SIMPSON_HPP
#define SIMPSON_HPP

template <class Function>
double simpsonIntegrator(Function&& f, double a, double b, int N);

#endif /*SIMPSON_HPP*/
```

**simpson.cpp**

```
#include "simpson.hpp"
#include <cassert>

template <class Function>
double simpsonIntegrator(Function&& f, double a, double b, int N){

    //some code

}
```

Now I'd like to link the main.cpp file with the static library to be able to use the function simpsonIntegrator.

First I have created the static library with:

```
c++ -c simpson.o simpson.cpp 
ar rcs libsimpson.a simpson.o
```

and then tried linking to it using:

```
c++ main.cpp -L./integrator -lsimpson
```

which results in an error in simpson.hpp:

`error: ‘double simpsonIntegrator(Function&&, double, double, int) [with Function = main()::<lambda(double)>&]’, declared using local type ‘main()::<lambda(double)>’, is used but never defined`

What have I done wrong?
Thanks a lot for your inputs!

Comment: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) may be appropriate.

Comment: `simpson.cpp` is your bug. You need to implement your template in the header file.

Comment: You are going to have to change your library to a *header only library*. Templates should usually be defined in header files.